# IndexOutOfBoundsException in the first row of Glazedlist table?

Tags: java, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception, glazedlists

I have build 3 Glazedlist table. when the user clicked on the row of the first table it shows list in the second table.
when click on row in second table it displaies other list in the 3th table.
Problem is when i click the first row in first table sometimes following exception appears.

**Does any body know Why do i get IndexOutOfBoundsException and how get rid of it?**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:546)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:321)
    at ca.odell.glazedlists.impl.gui.ThreadProxyEventList.applyChangeToCache(ThreadProxyEventList.java:175)
    at ca.odell.glazedlists.impl.gui.ThreadProxyEventList.access$600(ThreadProxyEventList.java:68)
    at ca.odell.glazedlists.impl.gui.ThreadProxyEventList$UpdateRunner.listChanged(ThreadProxyEventList.java:237)
    at ca.odell.glazedlists.event.ListEventAssembler$ListEventFormat.fire(ListEventAssembler.java:412)
    at ca.odell.glazedlists.event.ListEventAssembler$ListEventFormat.fire(ListEventAssembler.java:409)
    at ca.odell.glazedlists.event.SequenceDependenciesEventPublisher$SubjectAndListener.firePendingEvent(SequenceDependenciesEventPublisher.java:445)
    at ca.odell.glazedlists.event.SequenceDependenciesEventPublisher.fireEvent(SequenceDependenciesEventPublisher.java:344)
    at ca.odell.glazedlists.event.ListEventAssembler.commitEvent(ListEventAssembler.java:316)
    at ca.odell.glazedlists.impl.gui.ThreadProxyEventList$UpdateRunner.run(ThreadProxyEventList.java:225)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:461)
    at di.pri.debutil.gui.debEventQueue.dispatchEvent(debEventQueue.java:63)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:157)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:149)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:110)
```

**Code:**

```
// build the table
EventList<Treat> TreatEventList = summaryModel.getTreatEvenList();
String[] propertyNames = new String[]{"PlanId", "Number", "Type","dication","stimulation","dication2","Date","Outcome","rank","version"};
String[] columnLabels = new String[]{"pnr", "NBNR", "handeling","Supp","Stim1","Stim2","date","Outcome","Rank","Version"};
TableFormat<Treat> tableFormat = GlazedLists.tableFormat(Treat.class, propertyNames, columnLabels);
SortedList<Treat> TreatSortedList = new SortedList<Treat>(TreatEventList, null);
cabinaTable = new WebTable(new EventTableModel<Treat>(TreatSortedList, tableFormat)); 

// Configure the Table
TableComparatorChooser tableSorter = TableComparatorChooser.install(cabinaTable, TreatSortedList, TableComparatorChooser.SINGLE_COLUMN);
tableSorter.appendComparator(1, 0, true);
cabinaTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
cabinaTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
cabinaTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int row = cabinaTable.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
        DHDPnr = cabinaTable.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
        //at this point i set the evntlist for second Glazedlist table
        summaryModel.retrieveAllPredomainWithDHDPnr(dosNr(), DHDPnr);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when the user clicked on the row of the first table it shows list in the second table. when click on row in second table it displaies other list in the 3th table

This gives me a hint that you could be using 1-based indexing instead of 0-based indexing, also leading to `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when trying to access an empty ArrayList with index 0.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell with the code shown, but somewhere in the code when you click on the first row and it is trying to get the data, there is no data. So when you fill the data that should be there it isn't doing that for some reason. It would be easier to tell by looking at all the code as I haven't used GlazedLists before.

Size: 0 means it missed filling the data or something was null.